# Maven release process consistently failing : svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/tester/!svn/bc/170' forbidden

Tags: maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I have been banging my head for quite a while now and I have actually learnt lots of this issues on stackoverflow an pretty sure I covered some of the common mistakes(besides,I have done several releases with bitbucket and github) that were starring at me. But still I have not been able to release anything. I feel like it's time to shout for a little help :)

I use a self hosted subversion managed by [usvn](http://www.usvn.info/) and a sonatype private nexus repository. I have a multi module maven project arrange in a parent and sub module model.

Below is the snippet of the parent pom that is relevant

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*ITest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}    </encoding>
                    <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding} </encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean verify -DenableIT=true</preparationGoals>
                      <tagBase>https://repo.mysvnserver.com/svn/tester/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>dal</id>
               <url>http://nexus.mynexusserver.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<scm>
                       <connection>scm:svn:https://username@repo.mysvnserver.com/svn/tester</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://username@repo.mysvnserver.com/svn/tester</developerConnection>
      <url>https://repo.mysvnserver.com/usvn/project/tester/browser</url>
    <tag>tester</tag>
</scm>
```

Below is my settings.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <settings >
  <localRepository>/home/joseph/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <servers>
    <server>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <id>nexus</id>
    </server>
<server>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <id>dal</id>
    </server>
</servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://nexus.mynexusserver.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
    <repository>
                <id>dal</id>
                <url>http://nexus.mynexusserver.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Since it would probably too much to put the output here , please find it on [paste.ee](https://paste.ee/p/u4IOX) .

I am more convince this is either configuration issue on subversion side because things looks fairly ok to me. Can anyone point out something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Probably permissions are missing for the user. Just try to perform the same commands (see your ouput, they should be there) using a svn client. Your SVN structure looks strange too, usually you would copy _http://mysvn.mycompany.com/repo/trunk_ to _http://mysvn.mycompany.com/repo/tags_ not the complete _http://mysvn.mycompany.com/repo_

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. We branch out release candidates. we stabilize it in the branch and release it from the branch before merging  back to the trunk. For some project we release from trunk . I am not sure I understand what you mean by complete repo. Thanks

Comment: I just mean that  _https://repo.mysvnserver.com/usvn/project/tester/browser_ doesn't look like a trunk or branch URL, but anyway your error should rather come from authorization issues, so just be sure it works outside of Maven.

Comment: According to documentation scm url, the URL to the project's browsable SCM repository, such as ViewVC or Fisheye. since usvn has a kind of browsing of the repo, I used it there.

Comment: Well, I guess you mean the "base" Maven doc: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM.  For a project that will effectively use the values of these tags to perform operations on a SCM repo, I think you should take a look at the SCM plugin doc: http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Hello @Tome you made a very valid point. I was confusing this indeed. I got it working . Do you mind having this as a answer so I mark it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCM part of your POM looks **not related to an actual SVN branch** (**or the trun**k) of a project. For the SCM-linked part of the release plugin to work, I guess an SCM configuration closer to [what is described in the SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) should be made. A project POM SCM information should describe where to get the source code related to that **exact project version**, not the root project location.

I guess that without this, SVN can trigger unexpected authorization issues as you are in fact trying to access an URL where you might not have set permissions.